# hibernate-search, spatial queries and the new lucene spatial module

Tags: hibernate, solr, lucene, spatial, hibernate-search

I'm wanting to perform a spatial search in Hibernate. In particular, I'd like to store some items with a latitude / longitude then query which items are within x km of a given point.

I have found that the [hibernate-search](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search) provides [support for spatial queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html/spatial.html) through it's Lucene integration.

I also know that the spatial module in Lucene has been [completely rewritten](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3795) in Lucene version 4.0 but the latest version of [hibernate-search](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search) is using Lucene 3.6.2 of Lucene.

So, I have a few questions:

1. Is the spatial support in hibernate-search using the now deprecated lucene spatial module?
2. Or does hibernate-search use a spatial module from solr?
3. One of the reasons lucene spatial was rewritten is because it was unreliable / buggy. Does this mean that spatial queries in hibernate-search are unreliable?
4. Will hibernate-search be changed in a future version to support the new lucene-spatial module? (based on [spatial4j](https://github.com/spatial4j/spatial4j))
5. Assuming that hibernate-search will be upgraded to Lucene 4+ in the future, are spatial queries in the new version likely to be backwards compatible with the current hibernate-search API's?

Comment: FYI the Lucene 3 spatial module was buggy.  I heard it "seemed to work" in the continental U.S. but elsewhere, not so much.  Hopefully someone who works on Hibernate-search can provide a real answer to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No it was not, we where lucky enough to get a geolocation field expert joining the team for your same reasons: Nicolas wanted to avoid using the spatial module in Lucene because of its problems.
2. No it's a set of custom Lucene components; the embedded nature of Hibernate Search made our requirements very simple, at least in terms of Lucene integration (distance math is still interesting).
3. The limitations from the original module where of inspiration and motivation to the creation of the new extension, so I believe not, assuming it's the same known limitations we talk about.
4. That is very likely, our focus at this point is to provide a sensible and practical API; with the relatively simple functionality covered today we might not need to rush on it, but we're not excluding integrating it. A better support for Spatial types is planned for Hibernate ORM too, so we might want to integrate the custom types: help and advise is welcome, even if just in use case or wish form.
5. We have been very proud of our API stability in the past and will try hard to maintain the record. We will definitely upgrade to Lucene 4+ but this will likely have to break some APIs (not necessarily related to Spatial). We're going to try hard to keep changes to the minimum. This is one of the reasons to not expose too much yet: make sure we keep flexibility for the implementation, at least now that we're preparing for the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. My use case is this: Given two tables Item and Address where Item has a @ManyToOne mapping to Address and Address has a latitude / longitude, return all of the Items that are 1km from a point (lat / lng). If possible, I'd like to sort by nearest Item first and I'd like each Item's distance from the point to be included in the result set.

Comment: FYI, an example of using the new Lucene 4.0 spatial library can be found [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/branch_4x/lucene/spatial/src/test/org/apache/lucene/spatial/SpatialExample.java?view=markup)